Create a dataframe from a dictionary of lists (which contain a dictionary)
I have a dictionary:
data1 = {
    'AI': [3, {'G': 0.0, 'C': 0.31666666666666665, 'L': 0.3333333333333333, 'U': 0.0, 'J': 0.0, 'W': 0.0, 'O1': 0.3333333333333333, 'O2': 0.016666666666666666, 'T1': 0.0, 'T2': 0.0, 'N': 0.0, 'B': 0.0, 'R': 0.0, 'D': 0.0, 'M': 0.0}, [0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333]],
    'CY': [96, {'G': 0.010416666666666666, 'C': 0.0, 'L': 0.46875, 'U': 0.0, 'J': 0.010416666666666666, 'W': 0.0, 'O1': 0.41666666666666663, 'O2': 0.020833333333333332, 'T1': 0.0, 'T2': 0.07291666666666666, 'N': 0.0, 'B': 0.0, 'R': 0.0, 'D': 0.0, 'M': 0.0}, [0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333]],
    'PY': [127, {'G': 0.0, 'C': 0.0, 'L': 0.42276422764227645, 'U': 0.008130081300813009, 'J': 0.0, 'W': 0.0, 'O1': 0.4552845528455285, 'O2': 0.04065040650406505, 'T1': 0.0, 'T2': 0.04878048780487805, 'N': 0.020325203252032523, 'B': 0.0040650406504065045, 'R': 0.0, 'D': 0.0, 'M': 0.0}, [0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333]],
    'SR': [1, {'G': 0.0, 'C': 0.0, 'L': 0.0, 'U': 0.0, 'J': 0.0, 'W': 0.0, 'O1': 0.0, 'O2': 1.0, 'T1': 0.0, 'T2': 0.0, 'N': 0.0, 'B': 0.0, 'R': 0.0, 'D': 0.0, 'M': 0.0}, [0.33333333333333337, 0.33333333333333337, 0.33333333333333337]],
    'CV': [119, {'G': 0.03022827836191888, 'C': 0.09570154943733565, 'L': 0.1787022898077257, 'U': 0.059038954704106396, 'J': 0.01667767082036904, 'W': 0.0008338835410184519, 'O1': 0.46697478297033307, 'O2': 0.03193607185392467, 'T1': 0.0, 'T2': 0.08238175915743774, 'N': 0.0208470885254613, 'B': 0.00833883541018452, 'R': 0.0, 'D': 0.00833883541018452, 'M': 0.0}, [0.33216690905268464, 0.3354010574206815, 0.3324320335266338]],
    'BS': [65, {'G': 0.024576271186440683, 'C': 0.1033898305084746, 'L': 0.08576271186440679, 'U': 0.37796610169491535, 'J': 0.016949152542372885, 'W': 0.0, 'O1': 0.21864406779661022, 'O2': 0.07271186440677968, 'T1': 0.050847457627118654, 'T2': 0.013559322033898308, 'N': 0.016949152542372885, 'B': 0.0016949152542372885, 'R': 0.0, 'D': 0.016949152542372885, 'M': 0.0}, [0.3346524499339513, 0.3346524499339513, 0.33069510013209746]],
    'RD': [24, {'G': 0.041666666666666664, 'C': 0.0, 'L': 0.29166666666666663, 'U': 0.0, 'J': 0.0, 'W': 0.0, 'O1': 0.5833333333333333, 'O2': 0.041666666666666664, 'T1': 0.0, 'T2': 0.0, 'N': 0.041666666666666664, 'B': 0.0, 'R': 0.0, 'D': 0.0, 'M': 0.0}, [0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333]]
}

The form is:
d1 = {
    A1: [n1, {B1: m1, B2: m2, ...}, [p1, q1, r1]],
    ...
}

I want to create a dataframe that contains the top level keys (A's) of the dictionary as rows (so they form the first column of the dataframe), and the inner level keys (B's) as the columns. The B keys do not vary from entry to entry. The values m should be the cell values.
What is the most pythonic way to accomplish this?
I have read Create a pandas dataframe from a dictionary of dictionaries, but the dictionary here is nested inside a list, while that is a simple dictionary of dictionaries. Not comparable.

So n, p, q, r should be ignored?

What do you mean by "most pythonic"? Do you know any way to do this? Like, are you familiar with pd.DataFrame.from_dict()?

In the future, please make a [mre], meaning smaller example data. You only really need two rows and two columns to demonstrate this, and the values don't need to be such long floats. There are some related tips at How to make good reproducible pandas examples.

How is it not comparable? You just need to write a loop over the dict and select the nested dict. Surely you know how to do that, right?

@wjandrea I appreciate the assistance with rephrasing my question, but I feel that sometimes this is not appropriate. Most people know of a "brute force" way of doing things. However, in python, there is always an elegant one line method of doing things such as one that ouroboros1 provided. That is what most people mean when they say "pythonic".

@user2751530 that is a brute force way

You can use pd.DataFrame.from_dict with orient='index':
out = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({k: v[1] for k, v in data1.items()}, orient='index')

Output:
           G         C         L         U         J         W        O1  \
AI  0.000000  0.316667  0.333333  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.333333   
CY  0.010417  0.000000  0.468750  0.000000  0.010417  0.000000  0.416667   
PY  0.000000  0.000000  0.422764  0.008130  0.000000  0.000000  0.455285   
SR  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   
CV  0.030228  0.095702  0.178702  0.059039  0.016678  0.000834  0.466975   
BS  0.024576  0.103390  0.085763  0.377966  0.016949  0.000000  0.218644   
RD  0.041667  0.000000  0.291667  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.583333   

          O2        T1        T2         N         B    R         D    M  
AI  0.016667  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.0  0.000000  0.0  
CY  0.020833  0.000000  0.072917  0.000000  0.000000  0.0  0.000000  0.0  
PY  0.040650  0.000000  0.048780  0.020325  0.004065  0.0  0.000000  0.0  
SR  1.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.0  0.000000  0.0  
CV  0.031936  0.000000  0.082382  0.020847  0.008339  0.0  0.008339  0.0  
BS  0.072712  0.050847  0.013559  0.016949  0.001695  0.0  0.016949  0.0  
RD  0.041667  0.000000  0.000000  0.041667  0.000000  0.0  0.000000  0.0  


Thanks. That is nearly perfect. How do I give a header string to the first column (containing 'AI', etc.)?

You can chain df.rename_axis: .rename_axis(index='index_name').

Turned out that I did not need it. Thanks for addressing my query anyways.

I think you were just now confusing the index with a column. In out above, "AI" etc. are index values, and to give a name / label to the index, you can use rename_axis. If you then want to select it as a column you first need to make it one. E.g. using .reset_index(): out.rename_axis(index='not_a_column').reset_index()['not_a_column']
